# $watchCollection is not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

i have the following directive:

```
    app.directive('rickshawChart', function()
{
    return{
        $scope: {
            data: '=',
            renderer: '='
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs)
        {
           scope.$watchCollection('[data,renderer]', function(newVal, oldVal)
           {
                if(!newVal[0])
                {
                    return;
                }
               var graphEl = element.find("div:first");
               graphEl.html('');
               var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
                   element: graphEl[0],
                   width: attrs.width,
                   height: attrs.height,
                   series: [{data: scope.data, color: attrs.color, name: attrs.series}],
                   renderer: scope.renderer
               });
               graph.render();
           });
        }

    }
});
```

With the following html:

```
<rickshaw-chart
        data="sightingByDate"
        color="green"
        renderer="renderer"
        width="100%"
        height="100%">
</rickshaw-chart>
```

Here i fill the data in with the following controller:

```
    app.controller('CompetenceController', ['$http', '$scope','$sessionStorage','$log','Session','api',  function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage,$log, Session, api) {

    $scope.result =[ { x: 0, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 49 }, { x: 2, y: 38 }, { x: 3, y: 30 }, { x: 4, y: 32 } ];
    $scope.renderer = 'scatterplot';
    $scope.sightingsByDate = _($scope.result)
        .chain()
        .countBy(function(sighting){
            return sighting.y;
        })
        .pairs()
        .map(function(pair){
            return pair;
        })
        .value();
}]);
```

however from the debugger i am able to see that the `$watchCollection` is never executed.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ping check my aswer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `$watch` expression with `true` as a third parameter:

```
scope.$watch('[data,renderer]', function (newVal, oldVal) {
         //code
 }, true);
```

`$watchCollection` doesn't work for you because you have both an array and a property. In this case is like you're checking contemporarily `$scope.$watch('data'` and `$scope.$watch('renderer'`. And if a property in the array changes, the event will not trigger.

There are four types of `$watch`:

1. the simpliest is `$watch`, it simply check if the property or the whole object changed
2. the second is `$watchCollection` which watches if any property within an array changed (in your case this doesn't work, because you have both an array and a property)
3. the third is `$watchGroup` (since 1.3) which is the most recent version of `$watchCollection`, which allows you to check an array of expressions (but the same could be achieved with `$watchCollection` as you were trying to do
4. `$watch('object', function(){...}, true)`. This check if every single property changed within an object

This is a simplified version of your code, if you press the change value button, you can see how an element in the array is changed and how the event is triggered in the console:
http://jsfiddle.net/27gc71bL/

**EDIT**: I forgot to add something in my answer. 
I think there's a typo in your code, you are creating a directive using:

```
        $scope: {
            data: '=',
            renderer: '='
        },
```

This is not creating a new scope within the directive. So when you are using `scope.data` in the link function, you are referring to the `$scope.data` of the parent (the controller).

What I think you wanted, is to create a new scope in this way:

```
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            renderer: '='
        },
```

and, in your controller, bind the array you want to check to `sightingByDate`.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your response. I have one additional problem. Once it calls the function newVal is equal to [undefined, "scatterplot"]

Do you know why?

Comment: i dont quite get the last edit you made do i not set the data in my html saying that data should be equal to sightingByDate? and if not how would i reformat my code so it matches?

Answer (score 1):

As [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) said

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
>   the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array
>   items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a
>   change is detected, the listener callback is fired.

Watch collection is used for shallow copy of object and array only :)
And in your case both things are just value not array or object.

So I guess you need $watchGroup for your work to be done.

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['teamScore', 'time'], function(newVal, oldVal) {.. }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct as long as somewhere either **sightingByDate** or **renderer** is getting modified. Perhaps, this is not evident in your code snippet. Make sure any or both of these are getting changed somewhere in your flow to trigger **WatchCollection**